# Installed but Cannot Run Ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 on my Asus VivoBook S400CA alongside Windows 8 following a guide I found [here](http://www.akashjaindxb.com/2013/01/10/installing-ubuntu-on-asus-s400ca-touch-ultrabook-with-uefi/).  After a couple of starts and stops, I eventually was able to install Ubuntu on my computer, but once I restarted after installation, there was no option to run Ubuntu.  I checked my BIOS to see a way to boot Ubuntu from there, but there was no option to boot Ubuntu.  I tried accessing the boot menu while restarting, but again, there was no option for Ubuntu.  I thought that it might not have installed properly, and so tried installing it again, but the installer said my computer already has Ubuntu installed.  Any suggestions on how to run Ubuntu now?  Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy fix to this:

1. Start up your Live CD again and choose "Try Ubuntu Before Installing."
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in to open Terminal.
3. Type `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and let the command run.
5. Type `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Choose the "Recommended Repair"
7. Follow the instructions you are given.
8. Reboot when done.

Good luck with your install!

Comment: First, thanks for the suggestion.  I followed through with it, but ran into a problem at the end.  The boot repair runs, but then comes up with one of two messages: either "EFI detected.  Please check the options." or "EFI detected.  Please use Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourcefourge.net/p/boot-repair-cd) which contains EFI compatible version of this software."  I haven't been able to figure out what to do regarding the first suggestion, but in the second, I downloaded the recommended software, but cannot mount it or otherwise get it to work.  (see next comment for more info)

Comment: (continued from above) I tried following the mounting instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountIso) but no success.  I then ran Boot Repair and asked for a BootInfo summary which can be accessed at http://paste.ubuntu.com/6522955/.

Comment: You need to use a 64-bit (amd64) LiveCD and have a 64-bit installation. Otherwise, Ubuntu cannot start up in a UEFI configuration. So, you will need to reinstall, then follow the instructions I gave you, this time using the `amd64` LiveCD.

Comment: I think I must be misunderstanding something...  I downloaded the 64-bit version from Ubuntu and remade my LiveUSB making sure that I specified the 64-bit version, installed that over the previous version of Ubuntu, rebooted, and tried Ubuntu with the LiveUSB, and then followed your instructions, but still ran into the same problems in my previous comments.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by the amd64 LiveCD...  Is it anything different from the 64-bit version on Ubuntu's main site?

Comment: The `amd64` version is exactly the same. Downloads are just sometimes called that. Considering you are still having problems, I suspect you may have Secure Boot enabled. Could you see if you BIOS says that is enabled? It should be under Security Settings.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.  Secure Boot and Fast Boot are both disabled in the BIOS (and Launch CSM is enabled).  One thing I haven't been able to figure out is the Intel SRT.  I think several places have mentioned disabling that, but I can't figure out how to access it in th BIOS.  Might this be part of the problem?